# Looking for an example of non-unique weak solution to a SDE but unique strong solution

Tags: stochastic-processes, examples-counterexamples, stochastic-calculus

Everything is in the title, I'm looking for an example of an SDE with a unique strong solution but with multiple weak solutions.

Best regards.

Comment: I would say they always have multiple weak solutions, since an probability space on which you provide a strong solution is a weak solution.

Comment: @ mike : Ok I'll edit my question to be more precise. Regards